# Translation with a phrase containing "es gleich"

Tags: translation, meaning

I'm trying to translate the phrase:

> Sicher regnet es gleich...

What is the meaning of "es gleich" in that context?
I don't think "equally" fits so well

Comment: Regarding "es" read [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_expletive). – "Gleich" is referring to time, meaning "soon".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The expression is not **es gleich**. The **es** belongs to **es regnet** (*it is raining, it rains*). In this context, **gleich** means *in a moment, immediately* or *in a little while*.

The **es** comes after **regnet**, because the sentence is a simple *positive sentence* where, in German, the verb takes the second position (*Verbzweitstellung*) after the **sicher** (*surely*).

So the sentence means something like

> Surely, it's about to rain.
>
> For sure, it's going to rain in a moment.